# Open Local File From a Browser

Tags: javascript, html, macos

I'm needing to be able to link to a file that is on the local machine from a webpage (that I've built and am hosting on a local network). It's a Mac only environment, so there's no need for cross compatibility. I've tried using `href="file:///PATH/TO/FILE"` on an `<a>` tag, but I can't get that to work, and I've seen a whole range of explanations online as to how it is or isn't supposed to work, so I'm pretty confused at this point! The bottom line is that DropBox is doing this, when you have a file that is synched with your computer, and you go to their website and navigate to the file, this shows up in the corner:

[image]

It works like a charm, but I can't figure out how they're doing it. Does anybody have a clue how I can implement this functionality?

Comment: first of all, get all notions of how DropBox does things out of your head. that is commercial software and not simple at all. what exactly are you trying to accomplish? do you need to upload the file to a web server? As for loading a file into the browser, an `<input type="file"\>` will open the file picker. from there you can send it to a server with ajax or normal form submission.

Comment: one way i know is to use PHP and execute a program to open the file.  so on click send the file name including the path via ajax and run program with the file-name -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php -- just tried it on windows using "notepad test.txt" and seems to work ok.